# PowerShell SubFolders Size (at first level)

Tags: powershell, directory

I am looking to replace a VBScript that I wrote more than 10 years ago.  Basically, I feed it a path and it returns all of the folder size for that path.  For example, "C:" will return to me all of the sub folders (1st level only) and its sizes.

I wrote it with a recursive function.

For PowerShell, if I was to attempt and do this, I would use Get-ChildItem to get all sub folders at 1st level from the root. Then I would use FSO property "size" to get the folder size.

Any thoughts or better/shorter way of doing it? I am learning PowerShell. Thanks

Comment: This might be similar to what you're looking for, basically it's like the `tree` command combined with the folders sizes. https://github.com/santysq/PSTree

Comment: I was not sure how to use Linux PSTree since I am on Windows. I did look at Tree but that shows way too much information. I just need the folder size at the first level. Thank You Santiago.

Answer (score 2):

*Q&D (quick and dirty)*

Do you mean something like this:

```
Function Get-FolderSize
{
    BEGIN{$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject}
    PROCESS
    {
        $path   = $input.Fullname
        $folder = $fso.GetFolder($path)
        $size   = $folder.size

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name'     = $path
            'SizeInGB' = ($size / 1GB) 
        } 
    } 
}

Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 1 | 
Select-Object -First 3 |
Get-FolderSize | 
Sort-Object -Property Size -Descending

# Results
<#
Name                            SizeInGB
----                            --------
D:\AGuides              163.505494229496
D:\Desktop            0.0241866055876017
D:\DevProjects      1.99861824512482E-06
#>
```

Of course, I am using the root of D: without recursion.

Mea culpa, I meant to add this as well. Now, all that being said, you can do this in a more PowerShell'y way, with no need to call ComObject or function at all. For example, [***using one line of pipeline code***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2), and a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) and [.Net namespace.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-static-classes-and-methods?view=powershell-7.2) Of course, I am showing many decimal places, which one can adjust as needed.

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 1 | 
Select-Object -First 3 |
Select-Object -Property Fullname, 
@{
    Name       = 'SizeInGB'
    Expression = {
        [Math]::Round(
           ((Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem.FullName -Recurse | 
           Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB), 12
        )
    }
}
# Results
<#
FullName                        SizeInGB
--------                        --------
D:\AGuides              163.505493620411
D:\Desktop                0.024186605588
D:\DevProjects              1.998618E-06
#>
```

As for your comment...

> I was able to get this to work by sticking it into a variable and then
> use a ForEach

... I am not sure what your use case is for this route, but you can chain separate commands on the same line by doing this.

```
($AA = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 0);ForEach($oItem in $AA){$oItem}

# Results
<#
FullName                        SizeInGB
--------                        --------
D:\AGuides              163.505493620411
D:\Desktop                0.024186605588
D:\DevProjects              1.998618E-06
...
#>
```

The semicolon (PS has lots of special/reserved characters for stuff), allows PowerShell to execute each command independently.

This is fine for interactive CLI stuff and throw-away code, but not prudent/not best practice to do this in scripts. Unruly, extremely long commands are hard to read, maintain and support. Yet, I see folks do this all the time.

The aforementioned is really redundant, as you already have the collection, and can directly output that, so why loop it? Just saying.

You can assign output to a variable and output to the screen at the same time, if that is your goal, by using [PowerShell variable squeezing.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20variable%20squeezing%27&t=h_&ia=web)

```
($AA = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 0)

# Results
<#
FullName                        SizeInGB
--------                        --------
D:\AGuides              163.505493620411
D:\Desktop                0.024186605588
D:\DevProjects              1.998618E-06
...
#>
```

So, this one line does what you are doing with the ForLoop. Then of course I can array reference an item in that list...

```
$AA[2]
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                  
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                  
d-----         10-Mar-22     21:37                DevProjects 
#>
```

... as well as member dot reference its properties.

```
$AA[2].FullName
# Results
<#
D:\DevProjects
#>
```

Comment: EXACTLY LIKE THAT PostANote! Thank You so much!  What is BEGIN, PROCESS and [PSCustomObject] in your function mean?  I think [PSCustomObject] is a type object.  Usually BEGIN follows with END in other languages like SQL.  Is there a reason for the usage of BEGIN and PROCESS?  Thank You

Comment: YEP on PSCustomObject https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: In VBScript, we have to clean up the object because of memory leaks. Do we need to clean up the object in PowerShell? such as $fso = nothing?

Comment: No worries @LiquidMetal. It's all about PS advanced functions, and fully documented here: [about_Functions_Advanced_Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2).  Using PS ***Get-Help -Name SomeCmdlet -Full*** to get all details on a funciton/cmdet, etc, or ***Get-Help -Name SomeCmdlet -Examples***, just for, well, examples. ;-} You can use CRTL+J in the ISE and similar in VSCode to see sniipets to leverage. Many github snippet repos exist as well. Mark as accepted if that works fo you.

Comment: Full details of both .... [about_Functions_Advanced_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2)   ---   [Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: As for ***'Do we need to clean up the object in PowerShell'***, if you call objects, you should clean them up as well. YOu can wait for garbage collections for force it at the end of your script. I have default function for this step.

Comment: Thanks postAnote.  I have been looking at your code for the last hour.  You are currently using $Input.Fullname.  What if I want to put PARAM into your function and pass the FullName as parameter, can you show me out to pass it in?  I have been stuck for the last hour.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by sticking it into a variable and then use a ForEach. But is it possible to have it in one statement like yours? $AA = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 0
ForEach($oItem in $AA)

Comment: Since this is getting long, we need to move to chat, if there is more.

Comment: Actually @PostANote, I researched it all night with the help of @zett42. He was able to give me this piece of code which now I know how to do PARAM function. `[parameter (valueFromPipeline=$true )]` Want to thank you for helping me on thread. I have enough to play around and keep busy for awhile learning this stuff.

Comment: Good stuff and no worries. Take care and stay safe out there.  ;-}